# heatmap.2 Gaps Between Pixels

Tags: r, svg, heatmap, postscript, eps

Not sure if this is heatmap.2 or R specific, but when I save a postscript (.eps or .svg) there are gaps between pixels, is there any way to stop this from happening? They also seem inconsistent as I can't see this white space between all the pixels.

Comment: Well its really hard to comment without an example to look at! If the heatmap is a bitmap, then I'd have to assume its whatever is generating the bitmap causing the problem (and I'd guess that is heatmap.2). Since the gaps exist in two different formats I'd be inclined to believe it **is** a bitmap, and that its generated with the gaps, and this is therefore not a problem with SVG or EPS, but the generating application.